# Proving 1 function is injective

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given: 
$f: A \to B$
$h: B \to B$
$g: A \to A$
$g$ and $h$ are injective and onto. If $h\circ f\circ g$ is injective, how should I go around proving that $f$ is injective? I succeeded the opposite direction (combination of two injectives)

Comment: This really doesn't show any effort at all. What did you try already?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f$ is not injective. Thus there is $a,b\in A$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$.
As $g$ is injective and onto there are two different elements $a_0$ and $b_0$ in $A$ such that $f(a_0)=a$ and $f(b_0)=b$ hence:
$$h(f(g(a_0)))= h(f(a))$$
and $$h(f(g(b_0)))=h(f(b))$$
Since $f(a)=f(b)$ we thus conclude that 
$$h(f(g(b_0)))=h(f(g(a_0)))$$
But then $h\circ f\circ g\circ$ is not injective as $b_0\neq a_0$. Thus we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If $g$ and $h$ are injective and onto, they have an inverse, $g^{-1}$ and  $h^{-1}$. Now
$$f=h^{-1}\circ(h\circ f\circ g)\circ g^{-1}$$
is the composition of $3$ injections, hence is an injection.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!